# Set UITabBarItem Attributes Before Its View Loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m trying to change the colour of the titles of a UITabBar.

I’ve got this code in each of the view controllers’ `viewDidLoad`s:

```
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : 
      [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : 
      [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This only half-works as the colour changes from the defaults only after the view has loaded (so, after the tab bar item has been tapped at least once). This isn't the behaviour I'm looking for, I would like the colours to be set as soon as the app launches.

Putting the code in the view controllers’ `initWithNibName:` doesn’t work at all.

Is there any way I can address the `tabBarItem`s from the App Delegate’s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

**Update:**

The answer I marked as correct below works, though I've also found an alternate method, which works better if you want to address individual `UITabBarItem`s. From the Tab Bar Controller, after you’ve assigned the tab bar to a pointer either through creating an outlet from Interface Builder or programmatically, you can address the individual `tabBarItem`s like so (for a UITabBar pointed to by `tabBar`):

```
UITabBarItem *tab1 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex: 0];
UITabBarItem *tab2 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex: 1];
```

etc...

Then you can do stuff like

```
[tab1 setTitleTextAttributes:]
```

and all kinds of other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into UIAppearance.
https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Create a utility class to for your desired appearance for your tabbar and navigation bar. Then from the App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, call that class. Here's an example to get you started:

```
+ (void) setUpTabBarAppearance
{
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Your Font" size:15], UITextAttributeFont, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor greenColor] }forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Then from your app delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, call: [utility setUpTabBarAppearance];
Also, by doing it this way, you only have to modify the appearance of your TabBar once, and not in every single class.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: Navigation Controller? Do you mean the Tab Bar Controller? Either way, how can I address the tabBarItems other than from their respective view controllers? There’s a .items on the UITabBar but it doesn’t have any appearance properties...